# Cannot convert value of type LazyMapRandomAccessCollection

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I am trying to make an old app written in Swift 2 fresh, updated to the most recent features and most of all, converted to Swift 3 in order to prepare for iOS 11 and Swift 4 (even if it's already late).

I have a few errors left after the translation process, but here is the one I can't fix.

Here is the error, coming from my refresh `favorites` method:

```
fileprivate func checkFavorites() { 
    if !DataUtils.isBackgroundRefreshInProgress() {
      let ids = favoritesTableViewController!.favoriteCityList?.map({ $0.id })
      if let ids = ids, ids.count > 0 {
          DataUtils.refreshCity(ids) { () -> Void in
              self.favoritesTableViewController.refresh()
          })
      }
    }
  }
```

Here are some prototypes and informations concerning variables:

```
var favoriteCityList: Results<City>?
```

Obviously you will notice that I am using Realm.

And here is the prototype of the method `refreshCity`:

```
class func refreshCity(cityIds: [Int], withHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {}
```

This is the error I got at this line:

```
DataUtils.refreshCity(ids) { () -> Void in
```

> Cannot convert value of type `'LazyMapRandomAccessCollection<Results<City>, Int>' to expected element type Int`

What should I change in my prototype method when I am using `List<>` or `Result<>` container?

Comment: Without more context, it is really hard to give an exact answer. What is the type of `favoriteCityList`? Is `id` supposed to be an `Int` and `ids` an `[Int]`?

Comment: id is an Int so ids is an [Int] But when I use map on a Result<City> type, it messes everything and I don't recognize types anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to convert the `Results<City>` to `Array<City>` so the result of the `map` operation will be an Array as well, rather than a `LazyMapRandomAccessCollection`.

You can create an Array from a Results collection using the initializer of Array accepting a `Sequence`, since `Results` is a `Sequence`.

`let ids = Array(favoritesTableViewController!.favoriteCityList?).map({ $0.id })`

Comment: Perfect. exactly what I wanted. Why do I always think over-complicated ...